# promise not work as expected misunderstanding?

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch-api

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response.json()); //why the data not logged and promise is logged 
  }
);
but work if i writte 
let response = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

why the data is not logged and promise is logged in the first code?

Comment: returning the promise to the .then continues the promise chain. The next .then is called once the promise returned to the previous one resolves. By skipping the second .then, you instead logged the unresolved promise that you still need to wait for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is *only* to demonstrate how you would get the data out of the promise (don't do it this way):

```
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(
  (response) => {
    // response.json() returns a Promise which we can call
    // .then() on.
    response.json().then(console.log)
  }
);
```

The second code is actually a shortened version of:

```
let response = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  // .then() refers to the promise returned by response.json()
  .then((data) => {
    return console.log(data)
  });
```

This is the correct way of chaining Promises.

As you can see, we return the Promise returned by `response.json()` and then call `.then()` on it.

The good thing about chaining Promises is that synchronous values (like numbers, strings etc.) get wrapped in a Promise so you can still call `.then()` on it:

```
let dummy_promise = (new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(1)
}))

dummy_promise.then(value => {
    console.log("im expecting 1", value)

    return 2;
})
.then(value => {
    console.log("im expecting 2", value)

    return 3;
})
.then(value => {
    console.log("im expecting 3", value)
})
.then(value => {
    console.log("im expecting undefined because we haven't returned anything in the previous .then() block!", value)
})
```

A little background information:

You cannot expect the result of a Promise to be available immediately.

This is why you use `.then()` - it's a way of saying "call this function when the value IS available".

When you `console.log(response.json())` you get the Promise object, but not it's resolved value.

Note: Even if the Promise itself was resolved, `response.json()` will continue to give you the Promise object itself.

You can still call `.then()` on it and your function will be called with the resolved value.

I hope this small example shows what I mean:

```
// returns a Promise that gets resolved to "hello!" after
// 100 ms (milliseconds)
function something() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("hello!")
        }, 100)
    })
}

// call something() and store the promise in promise_object
let promise_object = something()

console.log("Installing .then() handlers")

// call console.log twice after promise is resolved
// (means they will be called in about 100ms - when the promise is resolved)
promise_object.then(console.log)
promise_object.then(console.log)

console.log("Installed .then() handlers")

// wait for 1 second, then print promise_object
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("1 second has passed")

    // at this point the promise returned by something() surely must be 
    // resolved
    console.log(promise_object) // Still prints Promise {} and not "hello!" - that's intended behavior

    // gets called without delay because promise is already resolved!
    promise_object.then(console.log)
}, 1000)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: .then inside a .then seems like it'd be an anti-pattern too, but I'm not all that versed in what is and isn't deemed an anti-pattern by the powers that be.

Comment: That's why I prefaced it with "This is only to demonstrate" if you read on you'll see me showing the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

`response.json()` is returning a promise, so you need to await it, either by doing what you did in the second example, or using `async` and `await`:

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(
  async (response) => {
    console.log(await response.json());
  }
);
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hy15ve68/

Comment: god bless you thanks

Comment: `.then(async () => {})` is an anti-pattern